# C++ I don`t know process of output in this code(parent class-child)

Tags: c++, parent-child

Here is the Answer.

```
A()
B(int)
C(int)
~C()
~B()
~A()
```

But I don`t know why I get this output.

```
class A {
public:
    A() { cout << "A()\n"; }
    ~A() { cout << "~A()\n"; }
};

class B : public A {
public:
    B() { cout << "B()\n"; }
    B(int i) { cout << "B(int)\n"; }
    ~B() { cout << "~B()\n"; }
};

class C : public B {
public:
    C() { cout << "C()\n"; }
    C(int i) : B(i) { cout << "C(int)\n"; }
    ~C() { cout << "~C()\n"; } 
};

void main() {
    C *b = new C(3);
    delete b;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`C(int)` *explicitly* calls `B(int)` in its member initialization list before then logging itself in its body.

`B(int)` *implicitly* calls `A()` before then logging itself in its body.

Base classes are constructed before derived classes.  This is why you see the constructors logged as `A()`, then `B(int)`, then `C(int)`.

`~C()` *implicitly* calls `~B()` at the end after logging itself.

`~B()` *implicitly* calls `~A()` at the end after logging itself.

Base classes are destructed after derived classes.  This is why you see the destructors logged as `~C()`, then `~B()`, then `~A()`.

Any [decent C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/) or tutorial should cover how constructors and destructors are called in relation to each other in a parent/child hierarchy.

Comment: Thank yo so much. Thanks to you for understanding this.!! I hope you Have a nice day